# TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not _io.BufferedReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, spyder

I am taking multiple pdf files in the same folder, converting those into csv files and then adding those to a dataframe. In doing so, I'm converting the file name of PDFs into recursive names (viz. 1,2,3,..) and then doing the same for the csv files using os.rename() function. While doing so, error is coming up

> TypeError: rename: src should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not _io.BufferedReader

I'm open to making major changes to the code too in case I'm using a wrong approach.

```
for files in glob.glob(path+"/*.pdf"):
    with open(files, 'rb') as pdf_file:
    
        read_pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdf_file)
        page = read_pdf.getPage(0-1)
        text = page.extractText()
        text = " ".join(text.split())

        start = ['from']
        end = ['to']
        text = get_keyword(start, end, text)
        DateList = [text]
        print(text)
        #pdf_file.close()
        
        os.rename(pdf_file,str(i)+".pdf")
    
        tabula.convert_into(str(i)+".pdf", str(i)+".csv", output_format="csv", pages='all')
        
        xlist.append(DateList)
        xlist.append(pd.read_csv(str(i)))
        xmerged = pd.DataFrame()
        i=i+1
```

Comment: `os.rename()` expects a *filename*, which is the string in your confusingly named variable `files`. But your code is passing it the open file object in `pdf_file`. And the rename is likely to fail if you don't close it beforehand.

Comment: @BoarGules, I'll remove the # in front of pdf_file.close() and close it. What else shall I do to make it work? I've literally made changes on this 1 py file for 30+ hours. Still can't get it done

Comment: Fix your call to `os.rename()`. That may not fix all the problems, but that is what you asked about. It does happen quite often that fixing one error doesn't make the code work, it just reveals another error, on the same line or the next. Then you still do not see a working program, only a different error message. It takes some novice programmers a few months to learn that that is actually progress. They tend to report *That fix didn't work*, because it is hard to accept at first that two lines of code might contain 5 errors, *all* of which have to be fixed before the program will run.

Comment: Something else you probably need to fix is `read_pdf.getPage(0-1)`. That call is the same as `read_pdf.getPage(-1)`. I'm not a PyPDF expert, but I'm pretty sure that PDF page numbers can't be negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help @BoarGules.
I barely even know how to code but I've somehow been able to bring the output with the files I wanted to with  trial and error.

ps. Am not being able to repeat  the same with another set  of files that are located in another folder. CalledProcessError: Command '[...]' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: That is a different error with a different cause. Post a new question with the current version of your code and the complete traceback and the error message in full.